# Moving the panel in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to move the panel/terminal in VS Code to the side of the screen instead of the default bottom? Like if I was doing split screen, but instead of code in the right window, it was the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as of VScode 1.14. We are tracking this feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2806)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be. There are no documented settings that allow you to do this. The split view editor can be swapped between horizontal and vertical with ⌘+Option+1 on macOS or Shift+Alt+1 on Windows but that doesn't apply to the panel window.

**Update:**

Support was added in version [1.18](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_vertical-panels) (October 2017)